# Век уточняется местом, или Можно (ли) сохранить авторскую интонацию?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

> Первое название идёт от древнеримского тракта, уходящего на север, в
>   сторону Римини и Равенны – Фламиниевой дороги. Второе связано с
>   культом Святого Валентина. Римский священник, обезглавленный в III
>   веке, был похоронен неподалёку от Фламиниевых ворот. **В IV веке, на
>   предполагаемом месте казни, построят часовню**, которая с тех самых
>   пор считается неотъемлемой частью паломнического путешествия.

*...На предполагаемом месте казни* - я-то не хочу, могу ли спорить?

Потому что:

**ЕСЛИ МОЖНО НЕ ПРАВИТЬ, НУЖНО НЕ ПРАВИТЬ!**

Comment: _...Построят часовню, которая ... считается_ Я бы сказал "которая с тех самых пор **станет**". Не воспринимаю я авторское согласование времён.

Comment: Ну Гриззли же, ну "построят" же по отношению к минувшему, а "считается" - оттудова досюдова!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В IV веке, **на предполагаемом месте казни**, построят часовню, которая с тех самых пор считается неотъемлемой частью паломнического путешествия.

Обособленный оборот можно считать не уточнением,  а дополнительным пояснением. А вот фраза из двух обстоятельств без обособления читается хуже.

Comment: Ога, вот оно што... )))

Comment: Ну да, обособленный оборот может также выделять, подчеркивать значимость информации.  Интересно, что в русском языке  одна и та же форма (обособление) может иметь две разные цели: выделив, обозначить как нечто важное или обозначить как дополнительную деталь.

Answer (score 2):

Первый раз вижу, чтобы обстоятельство места служило уточнением или пояснением к обстоятельству времени. Не могу согласиться. И зачем жонглировать временами глагола: был похоронен, построят, считается?  Согласен с grizzly: "построят часовню, которая считается" - не по правилам.

Comment: Спасибо за высказанное мнение. Но у меня же не одно предложение для правки - я читаю километры буковок. И прошу учесть главное правило редактора: ЕСЛИ МОЖНО НЕ ПРАВИТЬ, НУЖНО НЕ ПРАВИТЬ! Это - дань уважение авторскому дыханию. Однако всё поедет к автору, каждое высказывание. Пусть думает, обо что народ спотыкается.

Comment: Вообще говоря,  обособление - это более широкое понятие, чем применение правил  уточнения/пояснения. Это  грамматическая структура  предложения, которая используется для различных целей. Второе (обособленное) обстоятельство совершенно не обязано иметь связь с первым.

Comment: ОБОСОБЛЕНИЕ — интонационное и смысловое выделение какого либо члена предложения (вместе с зависимыми от него словами), придающее ему некоторую синтаксическую самостоятельность. В данном случае ("на предполагаемом месте казни") — что, по-Вашему, выделяется, от чего обособляется, тут самостоятельность (отутствие зависимости) от чего?

Comment: Если уж автору так важно выделить это слова (в чем я сомневаюсь, но надо бы у него спросить), то есть другие, менее "оригинальные" и более "читабельные" способы.

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу, что ответ принят, но позволю себе не согласиться с Jasmin: "...выделив, обозначить как нечто важное". А что тут важного-то? Было бы хоть как-то понятно, если бы это было **истинное** место захоронения, а так – только предполагаемое, и о нём уже говорилось.

Вот похожие примеры (в них нигде нет обособления!):

*В августе  2010 года в дни празднования 650-летия Спасо-Андроникова монастыря **на предполагаемом месте захоронения  Андрея Рублева** был установлен памятный знак  скульптора В.А. Суровцева.*

*Сейчас **на предполагаемом месте его крещения** возвышается Владимирский кафедральный собор.*

*В 2002 году **на предполагаемом месте старой библиотеки** была построена «Библиотека Александрина», в которой есть конференц-центр, специализированные библиотеки для незрячих...*

Comment: Римуль, спасибо! Автор порадуется разноголосью.

Comment: Важно то, что автор хочет подчеркнуть и выделить, на чем он хочет остановить  внимание читателей. А что у других-то списывать? Каждый текст индивидуален.

Comment: Зачем же Вы так резко: "А что у других-то списывать?" Я высказала свою точку зрения, **отличную** от Вашей, довольно аккуратно: "... позволю себе не согласиться..." — и привела в ее подтверждение похожие предложения. В своих ответах Вы часто используете примеры из Нацкорпуса, и ведь никто не говорит, что Вы списываете.

Comment: Римма, по-моему Jasmin имела в виду, что **автор и редактор** не должны списывать у других, автор имеет право на свой подход. А несогласных, таких как мы с Вами, можно обвинить только в удушении свободы самовыражения :))